# Fluent nHibernate, Auto-Incrementing Numeric other than a Key

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I have a situation where say, a `Notebook` stores `Pages`. At first, I had it structured like this.

```
class Notebook
{
 // ...
 public virtual IList<Page> Pages
 {
  get;
  set;
 }
}

class Page
{
 // ..
 public virtual int Number
 {
  get;
  set;
 }
}
```

That worked okay. Each page had a page number. I would have the ability to re-order pages in my UI, and update the number. No problem. Then I discovered I could use a Dictionary, and simplify it more...

```
class Notebook
{
 // ...
 public virtual IDictionary<int, Page> Pages
 {
  get;
  set;
 }
}

class Page
{
 // ..
}
```

And map it like so..

```
public class NotebookMap : ClassMap<Notebook>
{
    public NotebookMap()
    {
        // Specify the Entity Primary Key
        Id(x => x.Id);

        // one notebook will have a list of pages with page numbers
        HasMany<int, Page>(x => x.Pages)
            .DictionaryKey<int>("Number")
            .DictionaryValue<Page>("Page")
            .ForeignKey("Notebook")
            .Schema("Notebook").Table("Pages"); 

        Schema(Schemas.Collections ); Table("Notebooks");
    }
}
```

Huzzah, everything was right with the world. This works great. But I'm curious...

Is there any way to bind `Number` to something that will make sure to auto-increment per `Notebook`? Right now, I just handle this in my `Service` by using the `Notebook.Pages.Count` method when I add a new page. But fluent nHibernate seems pretty smart. Is there any way I can integrate it right into the mapping, so that anytime I add a new page, it just gets the count and makes sure the number is appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you really want to keep this out of the mapping.  You'd be mixing the application logic (Where should the next page go) with the model (how am I storing the next page).  Also if you make this column auto-increment you'd have to do it on a per table basis.  Unless you are creating a new table for each book, you'd (AFAIK) only be able to have 1 consistently incrementing key (as the native generator which uses auto increment columns in NHibernate is done via the database).

Comment: But if I keep this in the application logic, it should be fine to go ahead with this method? I don't _mind_ keeping it in the application logic, but anything that reduces the chance for error is considered good in my book. I am a little concerned that I actually have to use the `<Type,int>` instead of `<int, Type>` as my example shows. It only works if the `Type` is first - which makes little sense to me.

Comment: The problem with having an auto increment column will be that you can only have one per table.  Also the database shouldn't care or know what the next ID for a page is.  You'll need to query it before.  If you don't, you can just insert a new one (and if you have a unique constraint on the page you could even just try to insert it and fail if the unique constraint was violated).  Can pages be inserted out of order?  Or do you need page 1 to have page 2?

Comment: Order is irrelevant for data, only user interface re-arrangement. It could be pages 1, 194, and 108501410844 as the only three for a notebook for all it matters.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use an autoincrement column for ordering like that.  Use an autoincrement column to generate a unique id for a row.  You could always just keep it in an array or even a SortedSet (from Iesi.Collections this will have better performance than an array).  I would not use an auto-increment for this though.